# Unable to deserialize mleap bundle

Tags: scala, serialization, mleap

I am getting a java.util.NoSuchElementException:  None.get on the following code:

```
// Deserialize a directory bundle
val bundle = (for(bundleFile <- managed(BundleFile(bundle_path))) yield {
    bundleFile.loadMleapBundle().get
}).opt.get
```

The error is on the opt.get line

Comment: That's because `bundleFile.loadMleapBundle()` returns a None. Please read our guide how to ask questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

An [example from one of MLeap's tests](https://github.com/combust/mleap/blob/372cfa59991527c1a43efa75d8915cca7c3f1b23/mleap-executor-testkit/src/main/scala/ml/combust/mleap/executor/testkit/TestUtil.scala#L31) deserializes a bundle this way:

```
val bundle = (for(bundle <- managed(BundleFile(new File(lrUri.getPath)))) yield {
      bundle.loadMleapBundle().get
    }).tried.get
```

Perhaps you should use `tried` instead of `opt`.